# How to add https on Yui libraries links?

Tags: http, https, yui

How can i add https to yui library links, i have used (https://yui-s.yahoo...) but unfortunately it is not working with every script as it is not working with gallery and editor scripts. Even i have tried it by downloading  on my local but that also not working. if there is any solution kindly let me know.

Here is code examples:

i have added this script by downloading the yui.js file on my local and it calls other yui libraries.[i:e yui-min.js]

```
<script src="/yui3/build/yui/yui.js"></script>
```

even i have added custom scripts also by downloading them on local[which are called by above script]

```
<script src="/local_yui_lib/gallery-storage-lite-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/gallery-overlay-extras-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/yui2-container-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/yui2-editor-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/yui2-element-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/yui2-button-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/yui2-resize-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/yui2-animation-min.js"></script>
<script src="/local_yui_lib/gallery-node-tokeninput-min.js"></script>
```

But this gives me error of yui not defined.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gallery modules were never supposed to work on https://yui-s.yahooapis.com because they were community code that wasn't vetted by the YUI core team.

HTTPS usually means that you have full trust over the data that's being served over the wire there, and because of that, the only way to fully trust what's being served is to host it yourself.

You can use Ryan Grove's [combohandler](https://github.com/rgrove/combohandler) to create your YUI-compatible combohandler endpoint, though it may not be fully supported anymore.

Note that [YUI is now deprecated and no longer under active development](https://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/96098168666/important-announcement-regarding-yui), so be careful with the future direction of your tech stack there.

Comment: Thanks Leung for the reply.. i also got the solution for this by downloading the yui libraries on my local and do some changes in min.js of yui.